# Qt - Is there a way to trigger a Timer early and pass an argument into the Timer

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

A portion of my application (Weather.qml) currently makes a HTTP GET request for the weather every 5 minutes using a Timer and GPS coordinates. I also have a user setting (Settings.qml) that lets the user choose a location.

I was wondering if it was possible to trigger the Timer whenever the location setting was modified and for the Timer to take in the new coordinates to be passed into the HTTP Get request.

At the moment, I am just passing a GPS coordinate as an argument (`weatherLocation`) to the executable on launch.

Weather.qml

```
WeatherForm {

    // A timer to refresh the forecast every 5 minutes
    Timer {
        interval: 300000
        repeat: true
        triggeredOnStart: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            if (weatherAppKey != "" && weatherLocation != "") {
                // Make HTTP GET request and parse the result
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                xhr.open("GET",
                         "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/"
                         + weatherAppKey + "/"
                         + weatherLocation
                         + "?exclude=[minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags]"
                         + "&units=auto");
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        var a = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        parseWeatherData(a);
                    }
                }
                xhr.send();
            } else {

                ...

            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Settings.qml

```
SettingsForm {

    Rectangle {

        ...

        ComboBox {
            id: cityComboBox
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.Center
            model: ListModel {
                id: cbItems
                ListElement { city: "Vancouver"; coordinates: "49.2666,-123.1976" }
                ListElement { city: "New York"; coordinates: "40.7306,-73.9866" }
                ListElement { city: "Hong Kong"; coordinates: "22.2793,114.1628" }
            }
            textRole: 'city'

            // Trigger the Timer here possibly
            onCurrentIndexChanged: console.debug(cbItems.get(currentIndex).city)  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible and it is not needed. Just have the coordinates in a property somewhere the timer can reference it. You have direct access to everything that's in the scope of the file (except in delegates).

> I was wondering if it was possible to trigger the Timer whenever the
>   location setting was modified

You could, but that defeats the purpose of having a timer - the timer is triggered by an elapsing interval of time. However you could restart and trigger the timer then the coordinates change:

```
property string location : weatherLocation
...
onLocationChanged: timer.restart()
```

Just modify the code to use `location` in the place of `weatherLocation`. You can change the location by:

```
onCurrentIndexChanged: location = cbItems.get(currentIndex).coordinates
```

If you make `location` a property of the main qml component, it will be directly accessible from every object nested (directly or indirectly) in the main component (unless it is shadowed by an identically named source local property).

Comment: Thank you. I realized I was tackling the problem in the wrong direction as well. I ended up separating the HTTP GET code into it's own function in Weather.qml and using Connections to call the function from Settings.qml. Putting the `location` variable in my main QML component might be cleaner though so I will look into that as well.